# Namespaces with external linkage

Tags: c++, namespaces

The problem I have is basically the same as 'greentype' mentions at
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/12458/

I'm sharing variables through namespaces and a problem arises when I try to put my function definitions into a separate file.

Consider the following example, where I want to pass variable 'i', defined
in the main code, to the function a():

---

*** nn.h: ***

```
#ifndef _NN_H_
#define _NN_H_

namespace nn {
int i;
}
#endif
```

*** main.cpp ***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "nn.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace nn;

void a();

int main()
{
i=5;
a();
}

void a()
{
using namespace std;
using namespace nn;

i++;
cout << "i = " << i << endl;
}
```

---

But now if I put the definition of a() into a separate file ...

---

*** a.cpp ***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "nn.h"

void a()
{
using namespace std;
using namespace nn;

i++;
cout << "i = " << i << endl;
}
```

---

... then I get 'multiple definition' error when linking (g++ main.cpp
a.cpp -o main). If I make 'i' declaration in the header file 'extern' (as
suggested in other forums), I get 'undefined reference' error. I can compile when 'i' is declared as const in the header, but that's not what I want.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Any global object, like `i`, must have exactly one definition somewhere in the program, but it can be *declared* multiple times.

Using `extern` without an initializer makes a declaration just a declaration. This is appropriate for your header file, but you must still define `i` somewhere. As well as making the header declaration `extern` you also need to add a definition (i.e. a copy of the declaration without `extern`) to one and only one of your source files.

**Edit:** Reading your question, you say that you want to pass a variable to a function. From a style and code structure point of view, this isn't usually a good reason for using a shared (global) variable. In the absence of any overriding reasons you should normally define a function which takes a parameter and pass a value (possibly from a local variable) from the calling site to that function via its parameter.

Comment: So the only way to get it to work is to make 'i' global, i.e. put  the definition
 'namespace nn { int i=5;}' in main.cpp, above int main() (and make the declaration 'extern'). But notice that in the original example (where function a() is in the SAME FILE as main()), 'i' was not global - I defined it within main(), yet still was able to share it with, and modify in, a() through the namespace. That is the framework I need to retain, because I can't really make 'i' global, since it (and other variables I have and need to share) is CALCULATED in main() - I don't know their values in advance.

Comment: No, you didn't *define* it in `main`, you just used it in `main`. The definition was still in `nn.h` and it was still a namespace scoped variable (i.e. not a function local). You can still calculate values and assign to namespace scoped variables in a function such as main. It is probably better to have `i` as a local variable in `main` and pass it (or a reference to it) to `a`, though.

Comment: @PetrH, to be precise, it wasn't global because it was defined in `nn`, not because it was defined in `main` (as has been said, it's merely *used* there). To make `i` global, you have to put it *outside* any user defined namespaces. Put it above namespace `nn` for example. Currently, `i` is non-global, but still namespace scoped (not local).

Answer (score 11):

The header file should say:

```
namespace nn {
    extern int i;
}
```

This is a "declaration" not a "definition".  You then want a definition in one and only one file:

```
namespace nn {
    int i = 1;
}
```

Of course, a much better approach is just to not have globals at all.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing really to do with namespaces, and all to do with the linkage, external or otherwise of the symbol `i` in your various examples. By default, global variables have `extern` linkage, while global `const` symbols have `static` linkage - this explains why it works when you make `i` const. To resolve your problem, one way is to *declare* `i` with extern linkage in the header file, then *define* it in only one of the implementation files, as shown below:

header:

```
extern int i;
```

a.c:

```
int i:
```

main.c:

```
int main()
{
  i = 1; // or whatever
}
```

Note that I have removed the namespace for clarity - the end result is the same.