# C++ namespaces and multiply defined variables

Tags: c++, namespaces, definition

I have two C++ namespaces as follows:

```
#ifndef TRANS_H
#define TRANS_H
namespace Trans
{
   double Delta[3];
   double calcDeltaPositions();
   //and more that I will leave out for simplicity
};
#endif

#ifndef SPACE_H
#define SPACE_H
namespace Space
{
   double vels[3];
   void calcAccel(double DeltaVal[3]);
};
#endif
```

Now I have a main.cpp file:

```
#include "Trans.h"
#include "Space.h"
int main()
{
    double pos = Trans::calcDeltaPositions();
    Space::calcAccel(Trans::Delta);
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting an error claiming that Delta is a multiply defined in main.o and Trans.o How could this be since I have only declared Delta to exist in Trans?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Namespaces with external linkage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508081/namespaces-with-external-linkage)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the files `Trans.h` and `Space.h` is included in multiple translation units (cpp files - in your case, both `main.cpp` and `trans.cpp`), you **will** have defined the variable multiple times, thus breaking the **one definition rule**.

If you want a global, you'll need to declare the variable as `extern` and define it in a single implementation file.

If you want a copy of the variable for each translation unit (probably not), you can declare it `static`.

> How could this be since I have only declared Delta to exist in Trans?

Actually, you didn't. That's a **definition**, not a **declaration**.

```
//Trans.h
namespace Trans
{
    extern double Delta[3];
};

//Trans.cpp
double Trans::Delta[3];
```

Comment: We can tell by the error message that the second translation unit is Trans.cpp.

Comment: How do I fix this/ get the functionality that I want?